# iPad - cannot scroll inside frame

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, macos, safari

I cannot scroll a pdf called inside a frame in iPad Safari

```
<frame src="ebook.pdf" title="Content Frame" name="content" id="content" 
frameborder="0" border="0" noresize scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" 
noresizescrolling="AUTO" framespacing="0" />
```

I have already tried 2 things:

1. 2-finger scroll
2. Using object/embed instead of frame

But this does not work.

In fact I have tried a lot of things...overflow, height, etc..

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any tips or suggestions, if not the actual solution would also be really helpful and appreciated..Thank you..

Comment: Can you post a demo in jsfiddle and I will take a look

Comment: Sure..actually you can have a look at the same on http://ipad.atwebpages.com/test.html

Comment: Just to add, the page has 2 frames; one on the top is an html and the one at the bottom actually calls the pdf (which cannot be scrolled in ipad)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this article http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1484 you cannot scroll anything inside a frame when using Safari on the iPad. The frames always get resized to fit their content (this also applies to iframes). To do this, Safari even dismisses the values for "cols" or "rows" you made in the frameset-tag and seems to use whatever value is needed. Unfortunately, the frame does not resize properly for PDFs so they get cut off.

I think your best choice might be to link the pdf directly...

Comment: Yes right..Linking the PDF directly would work..But unfortunately I'll not be able to do that in my current app..

Comment: If you use an iframe instead of a frameset, would it possible to use JavaScript post load to readjust the height of the iframe back to the desired value so the entire pdf is visible on the page at once?

Comment: This should be possible if you find a Javascript-library for receiving the height of the PDF. I don't know if there is such a thing...but I never searched :) Maybe there is a solution in PHP (or whatever language you want to use)

Comment: I did try finding online if the PDF height can be calculated dynamically...But not found anything yet...Do you know any way of doing that using Javascript?

Comment: No, sorry, I din't find anything either. Does it has to be client-side or can you use some server-side stuff too...like converting the pdf to an image with PHP and get the height of that image...might be overkill though :)

Comment: Hey...here is what my findings are...using iframe, i can scroll through the pdf..though works only in older ios..think 3.2....But the same does not work in the latest ios...4.3

Comment: Sorry but that's not what the article says. It says that the scroll bars are hidden and that you must use a two-finger gesture to scroll up/down. Unfortunately this only works on frames with HTML inside them and not PDFs.

Comment: Well...it says both...which is a little bit confusing because why would you want to scroll in a frame that is "expanded to fit its content"?! By the way: did apple manage to solve this whole issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to display a PDF. The 2-finger swipe approach should work for regular HTML frames.

One option is to use Google Docs Viewer (http://docs.google.com/viewer) in your application.

Comment: Yes right..But as I said, using <iframe>, i can scroll through the pdf..though works only in older ios (think 3.2)....But the same does not work in the latest ios...4.3

Comment: Also I am a bit aprehensive of using Google Docs Viewer ..I mean is it completely free to use for commercial purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

You could hide empty divs at certain positions in the frame, and use jQuery to scroll to those positions. So the user wouldn't be able to scroll the frame, but they could click navigation which would move the frame to the pproper section.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for taking the time out and suggesting a solution...I have 2 questions for the approach suggested by you;

Comment: hmm, I didn't realize you were using the pdf as a src for the iframe. I don't think my method would work then. Is it not possible to export the PDF as an image and place it inline? Then this method would work. Sorry!

Comment: I didn't quite understand what exactly do you mean by exporting the PDF as an image..Are you saying just a jpg and then create a link to the actual pdf..If that is what you are trying to say, I'll not be able to do that, as the "src" attribute val is dynamic i.e. different pdfs get loaded in the same frame dynamically, based on where the user comes from..

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the [Ext JS 4](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) JavaScript Framework? On their forum they speak of the [possibility to show a PDF in a panel](http://forums.ext.net/archive/index.php/t-335.html?s=7f8752c5b4f856948f25e7fbe1138115). The forum thread contains example code. The solution is not specific to iPad but I hear that in general Ext JS works very well on iPad. Anyone else have experience with this framework?

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed when browsing StackOverflow on an IPad that any code in a frame that scrolls outside visible is not accessible.  I think it may simply be a limitation of Safari on the IPad / IPhone